# Server 2012 Windows keep freezing

Tags: office365, onedrive, explorer

We have a terminal server and recently it started with freezing various applications. The problem related to explorer.exe crash and for some reason it keeps freezing. I can see following errors in event viewer. Any advice would be really appreciated as we have tried various solution last few days without success.

Terminal server environment:

```
Windows server 2012 R2
Office 365 v16.0.16130.20218
Avast Antivirus (File shield and Remote access protection)
```

Errors on Application log: Event ID 1002 (Application hang)

```
The program Explorer.EXE version 6.3.9600.18231 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: 475c
 Start Time: 01da6559d9dd2d0d
 Termination Time: 65
 Application Path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
 Report Id: 1a77d437-d16f-11ee-821e-2c44fd82666f
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

And loads of these errors: Application Error Vent ID 1000

```
Faulting application name: msoadfsb.exe, version: 16.0.16130.20218, time stamp: 0x63fb49e3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.21615, time stamp: 0x64ffee7f
Exception code: 0xc06d007e
Fault offset: 0x0002dfd8
Faulting process ID: 0x206a0
Faulting application start time: 0x01da657bf4b10859
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\msoadfsb.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: 32afa510-d16f-11ee-821e-2c44fd82666f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```